# How can I tell if my motherboard supports DDR2 or DDR3 RAM?

Tags: upgrade, memory

I'm going to be buying 4 gigs of DDR3 RAM. I don't think I can run 5 so I'll just remove the single gig of RAM that I have in now.

How can I tell if my motherboard will support DDR3 RAM? I ran CPU-Z and have a report made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

crucial provides a memory finding tool which should do it for you http://www.crucial.com/

Comment: Thanks, but is that testing compatibility with my existing ram or for my motherboard itself?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the physical form factor: DDR2 and DDR3 [have a different pin count as well as a different notch position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM).

**DDR2**

[image: DDR2]

**DDR3**

[image: DDR3 Memory]