# Can I use DDR2 or DDR3 memory on my computer?

Tags: memory

I've got an old Dell Optiplex 170L with Windows XP that is running about as fast as a speeding glacier.  It's really just used for the kids to play on, but even they are complaining it's too slow.  Rather than spend a few hundred bucks on a new computer, I thought I might try upgrading the RAM from 1GB to 4GB.  Ran Speccy to check what kind of RAM I need, and here's what shows:

[image: Speccy image]

I see from this that my current memory type is DDR - but does that mean I can't buy DDR2 or DDR3 type memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if my motherboard supports DDR2 or DDR3 RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/147149/how-can-i-tell-if-my-motherboard-supports-ddr2-or-ddr3-ram) also see [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

Comment: For what it's worth, you could put together another machine for under $200 that would be blazes faster than this one. (Using Intel G530 sandy bridge chip). Old DDR memory is pretty expensive. I would recommend just building a new machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct, your system only supports DDR memory. Newer DDR2 and DDR3 modules are physically incompatible due to the notch being in a different location:

[image]

Also, according to the [official specs](http://www.dell.com/downloads/us/products/optix/170L_spec.pdf), the Optiplex 170L only supports up to 2 GB of RAM (although [Intel claims up to 4 GB](http://ark.intel.com/products/chipsets/23884) for the 865GV chipset). Specifically, it supports either DDR-333 (PC-2700) or DDR-400 (PC-3200) modules.

Comment: +1 for those pics. Just you beat me for few seconds. :)

Comment: +1 and answer credit for the pics and the heads-up about only supporting up to 2GB!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> I see from this that my current memory type is DDR - but does that mean I can't buy DDR2 or DDR3 type memory?

That's exactly what it means.

From [Dell™ OptiPlex™ 170L User's Guide - Specifications](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/op170l/en/UG/specs.htm):

```
Memory

Type                333-MHz or 400-MHz DDR SDRAM [...]
Memory Architecture dual-channel DDR SDRAM
Memory connectors   2
Memory capacities   128-, 256-, 512-MB, or 1-GB non-ECC
Minimum memory      128 MB, single-channel mode; 256 MB dual-channel mode [...]
Maximum memory      2 GB
```

Also, DDR2 SDRAM ins't backwards compatible.

From [DDR2 SDRAM - Wikipedia # Backward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM#Backward_compatibility):

> DDR2 DIMMs are not designed to be backward compatible with DDR DIMMs. The notch on DDR2 DIMMs is in a different position from DDR DIMMs, and the pin density is higher than DDR DIMMs in desktops. DDR2 is a 240-pin module, DDR is a 184-pin module. [...]